# Specific aggregation of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns like "weight", "price" and "id". My user is buying several items with different ids. I want to have a statistics of the whole user's basket/order like the overall weight, and overall price. 
To be precise I have a DataFrame df, and list of baskets with ids like:

```py
df.head()
    price   id  weight          
1   4.0    1    257.90125
2   4.0    2    87.52515
3   6.0    3    142.69750
4   6.0    4    444.77600
59  4.0    59   0.00000
baskets_list
[(587, 25, 11, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 12, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 13, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 14, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 15, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 16, 186, 587, 587),
 (587, 25, 17, 186, 587, 587)
]
```

I want to aggregate this dataframe by this baskets list(in basket I have list of ids of items). Hope someone can help me with this aggregation.

Comment: The most straightforward would be to create a dataframe of the people - where you have an index of the person with a column with the id of the product. Then do a left join with the product table on the id. From there you can group by on person etc.

Comment: @Chinny84 nice approach thank you for your help. One problem, that it will create this product table in-memory which will be heavy

Comment: I don't quite understand the last issue. Seems like the easiest would just be a dict comprehension, looping through your `baskets_list`, subsetting and storing the aggregated result in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension to perform each aggregation, subsetting with `.loc`:

```
baskets_list = [(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,4,59), (1,3,59), (3,4,59)]
d = {ids: df.loc[df.id.isin(ids), ['price', 'weight']].sum() for ids in baskets_list}
```

Now you have all of the information:

```
d[(1,2,3)]
#price      14.0000
#weight    488.1239
#dtype: float64

d[(1,3,59)]
#price      14.00000
#weight    400.59875
#dtype: float64
```